# Dynamic Forms, Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'b' is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I get an error while adding a partial form to my current form (kind of parent/child).

The partial form is loaded with ajax and there can be none to several partial forms/childs.

I got it working that every partial form gets an ID and I can save etc, but everytime I click on the ActionLink I get:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'b' is null or not an object
```

My ActionLink:

```
      <%=Ajax.ActionLink("Add Address", "AddAddress", new 
        {
            Prefix = ViewData["Prefix"],
            ListDivName = AdressListDivName,
            ListIndexName = AdressListIndexName,
            ListIndex = AdressListIndex
        }, 
        new AjaxOptions 
        {
            UpdateTargetId = AdressListDivName,
            OnSuccess = "ListApi.ResetAddLink(event,'" + AdressListIndexName + "')",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter 
        })%>
```

I googled around and found others with the same error but different Links

This error drives me crazy :) I'm new to javascript/ajax, might be an obvious error :(

Edit: Here is the function AddAddress in the controller:

```
public ActionResult AddAddress(string Prefix, string ListDivName, string       ListIndexName, int ListIndex, string lang)
    {
        MyAdress aa = new MyAdress { };

        ViewData["PageLang"] = lang;
        ViewData["Prefix"] = Prefix;
        ViewData["ListDivName"] = ListDivName;
        ViewData["ListIndexName"] = ListIndexName;
        ViewData["ListIndex"] = ListIndex;

        return View("_MyAdresseListItem", aa);
    }
```

The Javascript function:

```
ListApi.ResetAddLink = function(evt, ListIndexName) {
evt = evt || window.event;
var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

var Index = parseInt(document.getElementById(ListIndexName).value);
var Pre = target.href.substring(0, target.href.lastIndexOf("=") + 1);

Index = Index + 1;
document.getElementById(ListIndexName).value = Index;

target.href = Pre + Index;
}
```

### Update

In the meanwhile I tried some other stuff, when I use the debug.js I get

```
Sys.ArgumentUndefinedException: Value cannot be undefined. Parameter name: method
```

I changed the OnSuccess to

```
OnSuccess = "function() { ListApi.ResetAddLink(event, '" + AdressListIndexName + "'); }"
```

Now I get a simple "Object required" :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the event which was not passed correct in the OnSuccess function.... so I figured out to pass the information in the function rather than passing the event and grab the information from there...